# Where does constants, literals and globals get space

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I have recently learnt that its possible to change values of constants in c using a pointer but its not possible for string literals. Possibly the explanation lies in the fact that constants and other strings are allocated space in modifiable region in space whereas string literals gets in non-modifiable region in space (possibly code segment). I have written a program that display addresses for these variables. Outputs are shown as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int x=0;
int y=0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int a =5;
    const int b;
    const int c =10;
    const char *string = "simar";   //its a literal, gets space in code segment
    char *string2 = "hello";
    char string3[] = "bye"; // its array, so gets space in data segment
    const char string4[] = "guess";
    const int *pt;
    int *pt2;

    printf("\nx:%u\ny:%u Note that values are increasing\na:%u\nb:%u\nc:%u Note that values are dec, so they are on stack\nstring:%u\nstring2:%u Note that address range is different so they are in code segment\nstring3:%u Note it seems on stack as well\nstring4:%u\n",&x,&y,&a,&b,&c,string,string2,string3,string4); 
}
```

[image]

Please explain where exactly these variables get space??
Where do globals get space, where do constants get and where does string literals get??

Comment: "size a.out" can be used to validate Steve's answer (only to an extent).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Possible" is over-stating the case.

You can write code that attempts to modify a const object (for example by casting its address to a pointer-to-non-const type). You can also write code that attempts to modify a string literal.

In both cases your code has undefined behavior, meaning that the standard doesn't care what happens. The implementation can do what it likes, and what happens is usually an accidental side-effect of something else that does matter. You cannot rely on the behavior. In short, that code is wrong. This is true both of objects defined as `const`, and of string literals.

It may be that on a particular implementation, the effect is to change the object or the literal. It may be that on another implementation, you get an access error and the program crashes. It may be that on a third implementation, you get one behavior sometimes and the other at other times. It may be that something entirely different happens.

It's implementation-specific where variables get their space, but in a typical implementation:

- `x` and `y` are in a modifiable data segment
- `a` is on the stack. If it weren't for the fact that you take its address, then the variable storage could be optimized away entirely, and the value `5` used as an immediate value in any CPU instructions that the compiler emits for code that uses `a`.
- `b` I think is an error -- uninitialized const object. Maybe it's allowed, but the compiler probably ought to warn.
- `c` is on the stack, same as `a`.
- the literals "simar" etc are all either in a code segment, a read-only data segment, or a modifiable data segment if the implementation doesn't bother with rodata.
- `string3` and `string4` are arrays on the stack. Each is initialized by copying the contents of a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

> I have recently learnt that its possible to change values of constants in c using a pointer

Doing so leads to undefined behavior (see the standard 6.7.3), meaning that anything can happen. Practically, you can modify constants on some RAM-based systems.

> its not possible for string literals

That is equally undefined behavior and may work, or may not work, or it may cause blue smoke to rise from your harddrive.

> Possibly the explanation lies in the fact that constants and other strings are allocated space in modifiable region in space whereas string literals gets in non-modifiable region in space

This is system-dependant. On some systems they both lie in a constant/virtual RAM segment, on some they could lie in non-volatile flash memory. Having a discussion about where things end up in memory is pointless without specifying what system you are talking about. There is no generic case.